# File upload fails over HTTPS

Tags: php, apache

I have a file upload php script that worked fine when over regular http. But when I configured the server with selfsigned cert it no longer uploads files. I'm suspecting the move_uploaded_file should now be different but cannot fine documentation on how to fix. Thank you.

```
<?php

$fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"]; // The file name

$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder

$fileType = $_FILES["file1"]["type"]; // The type of file it is

$fileSize = $_FILES["file1"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true

if (!$fileTmpLoc) { // if file not chosen

    echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";

    exit();

}

if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "uploads/{$fileName}")) {

    echo "$fileName upload is complete";

} else {

    echo "move_uploaded_file function failed";

}


?>
```

Here is my /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf without the comments.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost _default_:443>
                ServerAdmin bishop@gmail.com
                ServerName 192.168.236.138

                DocumentRoot /var/www/html

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

                SSLEngine on

                SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key

                <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>

                <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>

        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Whilst lacking in error checking the above looks mostly OK so the fault must lie elsewhere. Has the FORM been modified or is the only change the switch to SSL with self signed cert? ( I use SSL with self signed certs and do not have this issue on dev server )

Comment: The only change is the switch to SSL. It worked prior to SSL.

Comment: The pages and others come up fine with SSL but the file upload no longer works.

Comment: Do you have anything in `$_FILES` variable? Did you dumped it after adding ssl?